# Javascript: can parameters be anything?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I'm finding it hard to find information about this: Can Java script parameters be anything? For example, I know a function parameter can be another function. But also a parameter of a java script code, can be a whole load of completely different code, some code you would not expect to see there as this other code is not listed in the function parameters. I've tried looking up about this, but all the tutorials ive found only show the basics that a function or indeed a simple java script statement has parameters and arguments and little more detail, can anyone explain this better to me and hopefully provide better links? For example, when used in java script as below, the css transform 3d has a number of expected parameters as described here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp 
but in the code below a + currentAngle + variable is also forklifted into the code, but when the transform 3d parameters are officially defined, no one says you can slide in variables as well. You obviously can do this, but I'm trying to find out the rules about it exactingly, so I can be in the know when I write my code.

```
var currentAngle = 0;
var currentDirection = 0; // 0 - Increasing, 1 - Decreasing

function spin() {
document.getElementById("myDIV");
setInterval(function() {
if(currentDirection == 0) {
  // Allow one complete rotation.
  if(currentAngle < 360) {
    myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ currentAngle +"deg)";
    currentAngle += 10;
  } else {
    // Change the direction.
    currentDirection = 1;
    currentAngle -= 10;
    myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ currentAngle +"deg)";
  }
```

Comment: wrap your complex code in a function and pass it as argument ???

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Are you asking whether parameters can be some functions but not other functions?

Comment: Please add an example to your question; it does sound like you're talking about callbacks though, where an entire anonymous function is passed as parameter. This is common practice for asynchronous operations.

Comment: @emma46, btw, welcome to StackOverflow.  As others have commented, it may help if you clearly explain a problem you're trying to solve or a concrete piece of code you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: Any JS value can be passed as an argument to a function. A snippet of code that signifies a value is known as an "expression" in JS (as opposed to code that signifies an instruction to "do something", which is known as a "statement"). So syntactically, you can take any expression `<f>` that evaluates to a function, and apply  it to any expression `<x>` that evaluates to anything by writing `<f>(<x>)`.

Comment: Short answer is: yes. Anything you can reference by a variable can be passed to a function. I imagine that by 'anything' you are wrapping your head around `types`? JS doesn't have classes or types. There are many answers about that around here, but in short it is a non-strongly typed language, allowing a great amount of flexibility. Nowadays JS is moving more towards looking like a typed language with `Typescript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments can be any kind of value.

Code is what creates a program and generally isn't a value within a program.

The source code which defines the function call can include any kind of expression that evaluates as a value in the position where an argument is expected.

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully clarify what I'm asking, Quentin and Asad you are the nearest to understanding and answering my question so far, so thanks.

Comment: You are confusing CSS and JS. In JS strings are just string. In CSS, the value doesn't involve any functions.

Comment: No, I realise it's CSS, but it's being used in Javascript with additional variables. I need to find a better example with just javascript, but imagine my example is all javascript and that i've asked the same question about + currentAngle +

Comment: @emma46 — Then I refer you back to the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Quentin, ok fair enough, I think you've answered the question there. What happens in the same scenario, when the code is not a javascript function but is just a javascript expression or statement, do the same rules apply? ie the values can be any kind of code, where is any official information about this please?

Comment: @emma46 that comment above makes absolutely no sense, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: It does, here's a better example: you are not using a javascript function, you are simply using the JavaScript String charCodeAt() built in Method. The only listed parameter for theJavaScript String charCodeAt() Method is 'index' as in this syntax string.charCodeAt(index) :however it seems in Javascript where the (index) parameter is you could also add in other parameters or even other code to execute first before string.charCodeAt(index) is evaluated, in this case the code might look like this string.charCodeAt(other javascript code(index)) -I've seen but I  want to find out the rules on this

Comment: @emma46 — `charCodeAt` **is** a function ("method" is just the name given to a function when it is the value of a property of an object). I refer you back to the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Yes, a built in function, ok agreed, but do you see what I'm asking from my example.

Comment: @emma46 — Yes, and I refer you back to the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: ha ha Quentin, don't worry you're going to get your answered question green tick. I'm just covering all the bases here.